# Bordism as a generalized cohomology theory.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Can you tell me, where I can find a proof of the following fact: The bordism functor is a generalized cohomology theory, i.e. we can find suitable connecting homomorphisms to obtain long exact cohomology sequences.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the book by Rudyak (http://www.amazon.com/Orientability-Cobordism-Springer-Monographs-Mathematics/dp/3540620435).  Or the old book by Stong. In any event, the main point is to use transversality to identify (co)bordism (of a point...) with the homotopy groups of a Thom spectrum, which is then the representing spectrum for the desired cohomology theory.

Comment: Also, I think these days one calls the cohomology theory "cobordism."  It's confusing, but there is a dual homology theory and it just seems better to call that one bordism.

Comment: Any proof that constructs an appropriate spectrum is the same as the proof that something is a cohomology theory. You go back and forth using Brown Representability. I suggest you try and find the map in the LES using this as a hint as to where to look.

Comment: Try Davis-Kirk, Chapter 8.

Comment: The connecting homomorphism for the pairs of spaces is one of the easier parts of the proof that it's a (co)homology theory.  The proof that bordism is a homology theory (I prefer to say *homology functor* as "theory" IMO is inaccurate and pretentious) is mostly fairly easy -- the part that requires the most care is the proof that it satisfies the excision axiom.

Answer (score 1):

See [Bordism and Cobordism - Atiyah](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=2050052)